# Is the 1984 Series of The Transformers the beginning of the story?

Tags: suggested-order, cartoon, transformers

My son asked me about watching The Transformers animated series. I looked it up on Wikipedia and it looks like there have been a lot of different reboots. Is the 1984 series where it all starts and how can I tell which version I have when I look at the DVD in the shop: I'm not sure how I'll know that I've got the right DVD or how to order it to ensure I get the right one?

Comment: I suggest you check on the Internet with your kid to know witch animated series he is referring to. As it's one of the must recognizable character, check the [Various version of Optimus Prime on the Transformers Wiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Optimus_Prime), he will point you out which one he know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There have indeed been several reboots. Even the original series contained two different versions: comics and television continuities. But to answer the question in the title: yes, the 1984 cartoon series (and the related comics) start at the beginning of the story. The first episode is set on their home planet, Cybertron.

However, I suspect he is referring to one of the recent reboots, [Transformers: Animated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_Animated).

Personal opinion: Transformers: Animated is geared more to today's youth. I suspect that, if you present him with the 1984 version, he will be disappointed. That is now mainly of interest to die hard fans (reliving their youth!).

Note also: the full list of series can be found on Wikipedia: [list of Transformers TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Transformers_TV_series), including the latest series: [Transformers: Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers%3a_Prime).

Comment: I would disagree.  My kids all love watching both the old Transformers series (which is on nightly on Hub at midnight eastern I think) and the new Transformers:Prime.  Watching the Transformers:Animated reboot made me ill.  It's not Transformers.  It's Pokemon with robots.

Comment: @BBlake No, "Robots in Disguise" was Pokemon with robots. "Animated" was "Teen Titans" with robots.

Answer (score 10):

Wikis has provided you with a completely correct answer, and I'm of the opinion that you should select it as the best one.

There is, however, something any price-conscious shopper should be aware of, should you choose to purchase the 1984 series DVDs for your son: there have been (at least) 2 different releases of the series on DVD.  The first releases, between 2002 and 2004 have numerous problems.

> Rhino's DVD boxsets have been criticized by owners. Various reasons
>   include that the episodes as seen on the Rhino DVDs are based on
>   incomplete 35 mm film masters, as opposed to the original 1" broadcast
>   master videotapes aired on television. Although the film masters are
>   very detailed and colorful, some of the episodes contain alternate or
>   incomplete/missing animation that was originally corrected/completed
>   for the broadcast versions. As a result, the DVD versions on some of
>   the episodes are less "finished" than the versions that aired on
>   television. Rhino attempted to fix some of the "new" errors, with
>   lackluster results. Most of the errors are in the Season 1 box set
>   with "Heavy Metal War" being the worst episode in terms of incomplete
>   animation and bad attempts by Rhino to fix the errors.[17]
>
> In addition, the telecine transfer of the film masters turned out to
>   be sub-par, and did not provide any proper 3:2 pulldown system for
>   transferring the 24 frames-per-second film to 60 fields-per-second
>   video. As a result, aliasing (jaggies) appear frequently in most, if
>   not all, of the episodes.
>
> Further, the Rhino versions of the episodes have a plethora of
>   newly-added sound effects from a stock sound effects library (which
>   many fans have said are annoying and distracting), sound effects that
>   did not appear in the episodes as originally produced and broadcast.
>   These sound effects were intended to only appear on the episodes' 5.1
>   soundtrack, but for select episodes in the Season 1 and Season 2 Part
>   1 sets, the stereo soundtrack also exhibited the added sounds. For the
>   Season 2 Part 2 set, every single episode's 2.0 stereo soundtrack had
>   the added sounds from the 5.1 track. It wasn't until the Transformers
>   Season 3, Part 1 boxset that Rhino bowed to the fanbase and added an
>   "original broadcast audio" option. These new sound effects were also
>   applied to several European releases of the Transformers series, as
>   well as to The Transformers: The Movie: Reconstructed DVD (although it
>   should be noted that Rhino's own version of TF:TM does not have the
>   added sound effects). Only serving to enhance the discontent, the
>   sound studio responsible for this, Magno Sound, claim that the sounds
>   were always there.[18]
>   (from the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers_%28TV_series%29#Issues_with_Rhino_Releases))

By all reports, the more recent releases (25th Anniversary Edition or "Matrix Of Leadership" Edition) do NOT have these issues.

Buyer beware - if you accidentally get the Rhino sets, the show will suffer for it.